# Sessão PHP não é configurada

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session

Estou utilizando `session_start` para criar uma sessão para o usuário quando ele for autenticado no server, porém a sessão não está sendo mantida na troca de páginas, estou usando requisições AJAX para fazer a autenticação, então:

> login.js + ajax -> login.php [cria a sessão se for logado] [mensagem
>   de erro caso não seja logado]   login.js -> [se for logado redireciona
>   para panel.php]

A sessão é criada em login.php(testei com `empty($_SESSION)`), mas na página panel.php a sessão não existe mais, usei `print_r($_SESSION)` e a variável não é reconhecida.

Alguém sabe dizer a causa do erro?

**login.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#go").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    client = new clientSnotes("log");
    client.sendLogin($("#email").val(), $("#password").val(), "log");
});
```

});

funções usadas por login.js:

```
function clientSnotes(){

this.parseUser = function(data, log){
    var xml = $.parseXML(data);
    xml = $(xml).contents();

    var error = xml.attr('error');

    //No error
    if(error === '0'){
        var user = new userFields(xml.attr('id'), xml.attr('name'), xml.attr('email'), xml.attr('password'));
        window.location.href = "panel.php?" + user.getDataUrl();
    }
    else{
        $("#" + log).css("display", "inline");
        $("#" + log).html(xml.contents());
    }
};


this.assemblyRequisition = function(parser, url, data, error_log){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            parser(data, error_log);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Failed to send data to server.");
        }
    });
};

this.sendLogin = function(email, password, error_log){
    this.assemblyRequisition(this.parseUser, 'scripts_php/login.php', 'email=' + email + '&password=' + password, error_log);
};
```

**login.php**

```
        if(UserDataHandler::selectByEmail($_POST['email']) && UserDataHandler::selectByPassword($_POST['password'])){
        $user = UserDataHandler::selectByEmail($_POST['email'])[0];
        $assembler->addAttribute("error", "0");
        $assembler->addAttribute("id", $user->id);
        $assembler->addAttribute("name", $user->name);
        $assembler->addAttribute("email", $user->email);
        $assembler->addAttribute("password", $user->password);
        session_start();
        //testando
        if(empty($_SESSION))
            $assembler->addAttribute ("session", "no");
        else
            $assembler->addAttribute ("session", "ok");

        $_SESSION['con'] = 1;
    }
    ...
    echo $assembler->assembly("result");//escreve o resultado da operação na página
```

**panel.php**

```
        <div id="content">
        <?php
            print_r($_SESSION);
        ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Você pode compartilhar o código para sabermos onde está o problema?

Comment: Porque não usa cookies? É muito mais simples. Mas assim como o Weslley disse, compartilhe seu código.

Comment: O código já foi compartilhado, poderia usar cookies mas o problema é que eles podem ser bloqueados e a session já resolve este problema passando os dados pela URL automaticamente.

Comment: Uma coisa que não tem haver com a pergunta,mas com o comentário,sessions utilizam Cookies para serem identificadas pelo servidor.O navegador passa o Session_ID e o apache identifica o navegador como portador de tal sessão.

Comment: sim mas caso não estejam disponíveis ela usa propagação pela URL para passar a SID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`session_start()` significa dizer à página que está disposta a tratar sessões.

Para acessar sessões,também é necessário o `session_start()`.

Adicione na sua página painel.php,no inicio do documento .php

Comment: eu adicionei no arquivo login.php e as sessões dependem da conexão e não das páginas para se manter viva, estou certo?

Comment: A entendi, muito obrigado cara, a sessão foi reconhecida, agora eu sei que é necessário chamar a função em cada página, valeu mesmo!

Comment: Certo.Disponha ;)